# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a JavaScript function to validate the month and year from a field. The format of the date on the field is mm/yyyy and the function that validates it's the one below:

```
function validateVencimento(){
    var valid = true;
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var actualMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var actualYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
    vencimento = vencimento.replace('///g', '');

    var month = parseInt(vencimento.substring(0, 2),10);
    var year  = parseInt(vencimento.substring(2, 6),10);

    if((month < 1) || (month > 12)) valid = false;
    if((year < actualYear)) valid = false;
    if((year < actualYear) && (month < actualMonth)) valid = false;

    if(valid == false){
        vencimento.addClass("error");
        vencimentoInfo.text("A validade do cartao esta invalida!");
        vencimentoInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }

    else{
        vencimento.removeClass("error");
        vencimentoInfo.text("");
        vencimentoInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

After i enter the date on the field i call the function above on blur, but the Chrome console returns the error Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace'.

Comment: Line number, please? A jsFiddle test case would also help a lot.

Comment: Where is `vencimento` defined?

Comment: Oh, not needed, there is only one `replace` in the code, hahaha.
Where did you define the `vencimento` variable? Is it on the global scope?

Comment: So what do you expect `vencimento` to be (it is not defined in the code you posted)? Obviously, it has no `replace` method (maybe it's not a string?)

Comment: Consider how this error can be minimally reproduced `x = {}; x.replace()` - what does that say about the object named by `x`?

Comment: @Matthew Presumably from an outer scope - or the error would be different.

Comment: @elclanrs, yeah, the Regex object should be only `/\//g` (no quotes, escaped `/`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using `vencimento` as both a string and a jQuery object. You can't do that. Perhaps make a new variable `vencimentoText` like this:

```
var vencimentoText = vencimento.val();
```

Then use `vencimentoText` wherever you're currently using it as a string (e.g., with `replace`, `substring`, etc., but not `addClass`, etc.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The `text`, `addClass`, and `removeClass` methods indicate jQuery to me in the absence of any other information.

Comment: @ ick: Yeah, sorry, I just saw those (but sadly didn't delete before you saw the comment!). I think you're on fairly solid ground there. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, `.addClass`, `.removeClass` and `.text` sounds pretty jQuery-ish for me.